# Insertion sort function with order switch

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I tried to write an insertion sort function that will switch between ascending and descending based on the sign of its argument (`order`). It works, but it doesn't look right because the conditional operator I used as a switch will add some overhead to each iteration of the inner loop. So I'd like to ask for your advice on how I could write a better version of my function.

```
void Array::sort(int order) //Array is a struct that contains a vector of pointers named vect, as well as this function.
{
  if (order==0) return;
  bool ascending = (order>0);
  int i,j;
  Data* buffer; //Data is a struct containing some variables, including the key that has to be sorted.
  for (i=1; i<_size; i++)
  {
    buffer = vect[i]; //A vector of pointers to Data objects declared in the Array struct.
    j=i-1;
    while ( j>=0 && (ascending?(vect[j]->key > buffer->key):(vect[j]->key < buffer->key)))
    {
      vect[j+1] = vect[j];
      j--;
    }
    vect[++j] = buffer;
  }
}
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ fits more

Comment: What was the downvote for?

Comment: I guess either someone thought it didn't _show research effort_ or didn't think it was phrased to be useful to a wider audience. Not saying I agree, but those are the conditions in the up/downvote hover text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You essentially want to write two functions, each of which knows its sort order *statically* (ie, at compile time), and choose which one to call dynamically.

The simplest change is this:

```
// original code, templated
template <bool Ascending>
void Array::sort() {
  int i,j;
  Data* buffer;
  for (i=1; i<_size; i++) {
    buffer = vect[i];
    j=i-1;
    while (j>=0 && (Ascending?(vect[j]->key > buffer->key):(vect[j]->key < buffer->key)))
    {
      vect[j+1] = vect[j];
      j--;
    }
    vect[++j] = buffer;
  }
}

// original prototype
void Array::sort(int order) {
  if (order > 0)
    sort<true>();
  else if (order < 0)
    sort<false>;
}
```

Note that although there is still a ternary statement in the inner loop, it can easily be optimised away since `Ascending` is constant (just a different constant in each instantiation).

A cleaner way is to remove the ternary statement entirely, and and instead pass *some kind of comparison function* into the inner function template. We could pass a function pointer, or a lambda - I'm using the built-in function objects since they already do what we want.

```
// Comparitor is some type you can call to compare two arguments
template <typename Comparitor>
void Array::sort(Comparitor comp) {
  int i,j;
  Data* buffer;
  for (i=1; i<_size; i++) {
    buffer = vect[i];
    j=i-1;
    while (j>=0 && comp(vect[j]->key, buffer->key)) {
      vect[j+1] = vect[j];
      j--;
    }
    vect[++j] = buffer;
  }
}

// std::greater and less come from <functional>
void Array::sort(int order) {
  typedef decltype(vect[0]->key) KeyType; // or use the real type directly
  if (order > 0)
    sort(std::greater<KeyType>());
  else if (order < 0)
    sort(std::less<KeyType>());
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand the comparator/comp part.

Comment: I've added some explanation. For further reading, you're looking for the terms _functor_ or _function object_.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a template, and redefine your function as

```
template<class T> void Array::sort(T op)
{
    ...
    while ( j>=0 && op(vect[j]->key,buffer->key))
    ...
}
```

then you can call your sort with the appropriate sorting object

```
struct LessThan : public std::binary_function<int, int, bool>   {
    bool operator() (int x, int y) const { return x < y; }
};
struct GreaterThan : public std::binary_function<int, int, bool>    {
    bool operator() (int x, int y) const { return x > y; }
};

Array::sort(LessThan());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want performance, you could write two functions, instead of one. But leads to duplication. This is where C++ shines with templates.